# How to get items from DynamoDB having incomplete key or condition?

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The table has two keys: `filename` (partition key) and `eventTime` (sort key). I need to get all items having `filename='myfile'` regardles of `eventTime` or  where `eventTime<certain_ddate`

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
response = client.batch_get_item(
    RequestItems={
        tab_name:{
            "Keys":[
                {'filename':{'S':file}, 'eventTime':{'S':et}}
            ],
            "ExpressionAttributeNames": {":et":{'S':??????}}
            "ConsistentRead":False
         }
     },
     ReturnConsumedCapacity="TOTAL"
)
```

I prefer to aviod `scan` for cost efficiensy, and it does not make much sense for me why we should scan the whole table if we does have the `eventTime` value indexed.

What should be instead of `???` ? Should I use something different?

Comment: Which key is the hash key and which one is the sort key?

Comment: @MatthewPope edited, `filename` (partition key) and `eventTime` (sort key)

Comment: You should use a query, not a batch get item.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html

Comment: @MatthewPope thank you, please convert it to answer and I'll accept it, you were the first.

Answer (score 0):

[GetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) will get you exactly one item (at most) using the item's primary key. Where primary key in your case is both the hash key and sort key.

If you specify only the hash key in a [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html), you can have multiple items returned. In your case you can return all items with a given filename.

If you want to filter the results of the Query using the sort key, you can apply a [KeyCondition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.KeyConditions.html). In your case you could use the LT (less than) operator on the sort key.

EDIT: You cannot update a whole partition (filename) in one go. You have to get the items using a Query, then iterate them and update them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

"Query", https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html, is exactly the operation you need. It will return all items with the given partition key (in your example, filename) sorted by the sort key (eventtime), or if you want, only the those items where the sort key is in a given range (e.g., eventTime